# Something similar to attr_accessor and attr_reader for modules?

Tags: ruby

This is one of those *my code already works but I'd like to make it simpler* questions.

So I have a module something like this:

```rb
module MyMod
    @property = 'whatever'
    
    def self.property
        return @property
    end
    
    def self.property=(value)
        return @property = value
    end
end

puts MyMod.property # => whatever
MyMod.property = 'dude'
puts MyMod.property # => dude
```

OK, that works. But I'd like the convenience of using something like `attr_accessor`, but for a module instead of a class. Is there such a thing?

Comment: Can you not just create your thing as a "class" rather than a "module"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define the accesors in the module's singleton class (often also called "eigenclass") which is basically a module in the ancestor chain of an object (in this case: the module) which is unique to the object. Thus, you can define things here that you could also define in a class context for the object.

```rb
module MyMod
  @property = 'whatever'

  class << self
    attr_accessor :property
  end
end

MyMod.property
# => "whatever"

MyMod.property = "something else"
MyMod.property
# => "something else"
```